# Will the javascript confirm box shows up first or jquery first?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per my requirement,first i have called the jquery confirm box later the javascript confirm box . But the jquery confirm box won't show up unless it shows or moves to the later code where i called javascript confirm box.

So i can able to see the javascript confirm box first and back of it showing the jquery one .
I don't know if there is a priority check or not .

please guide me .

This is the code i used:

```
     function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn)  //called function
     {
         var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
         confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
         confirmBox.find(".yes,.no").unbind().click(function () {
             confirmBox.hide();
         });
         confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
         confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
         confirmBox.show();

         return false;
     }

     if (document.getElementById('hdnusertype').value == "5") 
         {
          //Confirm message for creating multiple absences for teachers login
             if (gridRows.length >= 1)
              {

            //calling the function
                  doConfirm("Do you want other dates you would like to create  Absence?", function yes() {

                      var chooser = igdrp_getComboById("wdcStartDate");
                      chooser.focus();
                      return false;
                  }, function no() {
                      // do nothing
                  });
            //javascript confirm box
           var i = confirm("You have selected " +   document.getElementById('hdnAbsenceDates').value + " absence days, Do you want to Continue?");
```

Comment: FYI, "I'm using both jquery as well as javascript" jQuery is a library using JS, so that statement is odd

Comment: just saying: JQuery is a Javascript framework thus both is Javascript.

Comment: Uhm, shouldn't both pop up, jQuery's dialog is non-blocking, so if it's called first, the native blocking confirm will show as well ?

Comment: Just curious: Why are you using two different kinds of confirm dialogs?

Comment: There's no "priority" to these different kinds of confirm boxes, they just operate in fundamentally different ways.  The jQuery one isn't actually using the browser's built-in "confirm" functionality, it's simply modifying the DOM to display something on the page.  The default `confirm()` on the other hand invokes the browser's built-in functionality.  Can you clarify on the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: On my clients requirement of showing yes/No instaed of Ok/Cancel which is default one in javascript confirm box.So i used jquery for creation of custom confirm box showing yes/no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery's confirm box works differently than the native JS one. The JS's `confirm()` blocks the execution of every other script on the page until the user responds to the confirmation dialog.

JQuery's one, on the other hand, uses elements to simulate a dialog box, and do not freezes the execution of subsequent scripts. So, the next instruction will be called anyway, despite the user answering or not... That's why the second confirm pops up.

So, if you want to subject an instruction to depend on the answer of the user to the JQuery's confirmation box, you have to place this instrutions inside the `yes` or `no` callbacks:

```
doConfirm('Do you want other dates you would like to create  Absence?',
    function yes() {

        var i = confirm("You have selected " +   document.getElementById('hdnAbsenceDates').value + " absence days, Do you want to Continue?");

    },
    function no() {
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response LcSalazar.It made me clear why it is happening.I'll try your suggestion.